# Why am I seeing much more cron jobs in webmin than in `crontab -e`?

Tags: cron, webmin, incrontab

I am just starting to learn cron jobs. Basically I am going to use webmin to manage my cron jobs, I am also reading some basic information about cron jobs.

So far I've learned that `/etc/crontab` stores the cronjobs and `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` has cron jobs for different users, and that when I do `crontab -e` I can see and edit the cron jobs for current user.

Root is the only user in my Ubuntu 14.04, and there are only several lines in the crontab files I found in above locations. However, in webmin, this is what I see

[image]

It is a lot more than what I see in those files. So my question is: where do all these cronjobs I see in webmin come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crontab -e` only shows you the cron jobs in your user level crontab (which also exists for `root`). However, there are a number of predefined locations that cron will scan in regular intervals and executes all scripts it finds in them (e.g. `/etc/cron.daily` and `/etc/cron.weekly` for daily and weekly execution and also `/etc/cron.d` which can include crontab fragments).

All these jobs are listed by `webmin` but won't be displayed by `crontab -e`.